# Load html into asp mvc through jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

The following code was working fine in ASP:

```
// loads the video/presentation/pdf into the central div
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".video, .pdfdoc, .presentation").click(function (е) {
                е.preventDefault();
                var url = this.href;
                if ($(this).hasClass("video")) {
                    $(".onCenterBig").html('<video width="800" height="500" controls><source src="' + url + '" type="video/mp4" /></video>');
                }
                else if ($(this).hasClass("pdfdoc")) {
                    $(".onCenterBig").html('<object data="' + url + '" type="application/pdf" width="880" height="620">alt : <a href="' + url + '">test.pdf</a></object>');
                }
                else {
                    $(".onCenterBig").html('<h2>PRESENTATION</h2>');
                }
            });
        });
```

but I had to transfer the project to ASP-MVC3 and the only thing I changed was the path of the files:

```
...<source src="/Content/media/' + url + '" type="video/mp4" /></video>');
```

and

```
'<object data="/Content/media/' + url + '" type="application/pdf" width="880" height="620">alt : <a href=/Content/media/' + url + '"...
```

I assumed the problem is in the file paths, but it is not, as I use the same way of typing the url on another place (with images) and it is working fine.

The strange thing is that even the 3rd choice, where on click I simply write `<h2>PRESENTATION</h2>`, doesn't work as well. 
So I am thinking there is a certain way of inputting the HTML code, as ASP and ASP-MVC differs.

For loading HTML from string, into the page, on other places of the project I am using `@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@ViewBag.MediaWindow))` but I am not sure using `@Html.Raw....HtmlDecode....` will help. And I don't really know how to abuse it in the JS code. When I check the console of the browser - I don't get any errors or anything suspicious.

So, any ideas how can I make that HTML load ?

Comment: Since the last version don't work either, this seems to be a problem with js rather than mvc. Do you get errors if you check it in say, Google Chrome js console? If you place a breakpoint in the js code, does it end up there?

Comment: I'm guessing that there is a problem with your `href` value.  When you inspect this with Developer tools can you follow the link?

Comment: Check console for errors and do some debugging. Make sure JQuery is working at all and that you're even entering that code section.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I don't get any errors in the console of the browser. I even check with FireBug (heard it's a good tool).

Comment: You should have no problems with this.  Make sure to do a test to see that jQuery is properly loaded and functioning at this level of your application  ie: $(document).ready(function() { alert("yay"); });

Comment: @MikeHometchko - I was also thinking that my problem is with wrongly defining or not running of the jQuery library, but it is fine. I even tested it with your suggestion and I am warmly greeted with "yay" message when I load my page. :D

Comment: What version of JQuery are you running?

Comment: @MikeC. - `jquery-1.5.1.min.js`. The same was I running on the ASP, so I suppose it should work. I don't know why I get so many problems (not only this particular problem) by transferring from ASP to ASP-MVC. I guess because of the way the server side works...

Comment: For fun, view the HTML on your page and post the relevant HTML as well. I don't see anything in your JQuery that looks wrong.

Comment: @Syspect Did you inspect the Nertwork traffic? Are you getting the response for the server for this html? Check the response content and let us know it!

Answer (score 0):

Where is your js script?  Nothing should be wrong...I just tested this:

HTML

```
<div id="test">Test</div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#test").click(function () {
        $("#test").html('<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red; color: white;">test</div>');
    });
</script>
```

Perhaps try upgrading your jQ, although I've never heard of a version issue with any frameworks like ASP/MVC.

Perhaps try removing the $(document).ready() closure and/or use the .on() binding function in jQ instead of .click()

EDIT: I'm aware this is more of a comment but theres just not enough room :P

Comment: My JS is in the head. As it has been in the old ASP project.

Comment: throw it at the bottom of the page